# Simplest way to create simple monochromatic button

Tags: qt, qt5

I need to create simple monochromatic button, just black frame with black text (I know, with 1bit it will be ugly) on white background. Is there any method which doesn't need paintEvent to be re-implemented?

Comment: I believe overriding the `paintEvent()` is rather the easiest way to achieve this. However, alternatively you could customize the style-sheet: [Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is using your own style sheet.

A basic example could be the following one. In this example, we set a style with `white` background, `black` border and `black` text. The opposite when the user presses the button.

Depending on your requirements, you could set the style for states like `disabled`, `checked` or `hover`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>    
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>    

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();    
};

#endif
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>    
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton("PushButton");

    pushButton->setStyleSheet(
                            "QPushButton {"
                            " background-color: white;"
                            " border: 1px solid black;"
                            " color: black;"
                            " outline: none;"
                            "}"
                            "QPushButton:pressed {"
                            " background-color: black;"
                            " border: 1px solid white;"
                            " color: white;"
                            "}"
                    );

    layout->addWidget(pushButton);
    centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
}
```

Good examples [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton) and [here](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet/blob/master/qdarkstyle/style.qss).

Comment: Woow! I didn't know such way exists. Thank you!